# In React, how can I use "map" to transform an array of objects into a new array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, function, transform

I have a simple question regarding my React 16.10.0.  How do I transform my array into another array of objects?  I have an array of objects that have attributes

```
id
name
```

And I want to convert that array to another array with attributes

```
id
text
```

So I tried

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
     
    const tags = props.values.map(result => 
      {
        id: result.id,
        text: result.name
      });
```

but the compiler is complaining that a ";" is expected on the "text:" line.

Comment: I think you just missed a return in the map function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is interpreting the `{ ... }` as a block of code instead of an object literal. An easy way to get around that is to just add parenthesis around the object, as in the following:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const tags = props.values.map(result => 
            ({
                id: result.id,
                text: result.name
            }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're mixed up because of the implied `return` not working when returning an object.

There's two ways to return from an arrow function:

Explicit return (block body)

```js
() => {
  return 'something';
}
```

or Implicit return (concise body)

```js
() => 'something';
() => ('something')
```

You're attempting to use implicit return, but you're returning an object, so the syntax conflicts with your expectation.

```js
result => 
{
  id: result.id,
  text: result.name
});
```

This is not an object, but a function body. The function body is invalid syntax leading to the error.

You can fix this by using parenthesis, or by manually returning:

```js
result => 
({
  id: result.id,
  text: result.name
};
```

```js
result => {
  return {
    id: result.id,
    text: result.name
}};
```

For reference: check out the section "Returning object literals" in the docs for [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions),